# Supremum of the range of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence, i.e. $|x_n|\le M$ for all $n$ by some real number $M>0$. I am wondering if it is necessary true that $\sup\{a_n : n\in\mathbb N\}=M$? I think it is false because for example, a sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n=1$ for all $n$ is bounded by $M=2$ but $\sup\{a_n : n\in\mathbb N\}=1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Indeed, if $M$ is an upper bound of $(x_n)$, then any $M_0>M$ is *also* an upper bound of $(x_n)$. Sidenote: you really ought to state the definition of bounded more carefully, e.g. "$(x_n)$ is bounded if there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $n$ we have $|x_n|\le M$”; this formulation makes it clear that $M$ is *not* allowed to depend on $n$.